# update div without page reload using ajax or a quick tool

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form:

```
<div class=" modal-dialog p-3 shadow-xl modal-xl" id="myModal">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Agenda" id="form_js_for_c">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-danger"></div>
                        <hr />

                        <div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
                            <select id="destino" class="input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Localizacao">
                                <option selected>Select Location</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 bg1">
                            <textarea placeholder="Motivo" id="DestinoObservacao" class="border-0 input100"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class=" btn-lg btn btn-link float-right" onclick="AddLocation()">Add</button>

                    </div>

                    <div id="listlocation" class="tamanhopredefinido  overflow-auto col-5">

                        @foreach (var item in Model.Points)
                        {
                            <div class=" border border-1 card list_divs p-3" id="@item.IdLocalizacao">

                                <select required asp-for="@item.Location.Id" class="font-weight-bold teste-select input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Location">
                                </select>

                                <textarea asp-for="@item.title" id="DestinoObservacao" value="@item.title" class="border-0 input100"></textarea>
                                <p class="text-primary" style="font-size: 15px;">@Model.Date1 - @Model.Date2</p>
                                <button onclick="Delete(@item.Id)" class=" btn btn-outline-danger" value="@item.Id" type="button">Remove</button>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>

                    <hr />

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div>
                        <input id="ButtonSave" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

when I click on:
`<button type="button" class=" btn-lg btn btn-link float-right" onclick="AddLocation()">Add</button>`

a javascript function is called and add the select and textarea data to a div with id="listlocation". When I click on the button:

`<button onclick="Delete(@item.Id)" class=" btn btn-outline-danger" value="@item.Id" type="button">Remove</button>`

a request to a C# .NET controller is performed by deleting the database record.

```
  function Delete(id) {
        var Toast;
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/agend/Delete",
                data: { id: id },

                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.code === 1) {
                        Toast = Swal.mixin
                            ({
                                toast: true,
                                position: 'top-right',
                                iconColor: 'white',
                                customClass:
                                {
                                    popup: 'colored-toast'
                                },
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: response.timer,
                                timerProgressBar: true
                            });
                        Toast.fire({
                            icon: response.classAlert,
                            title: response.message
                        });


                        $('#listlocation').load(location.href + '#listlocation>*',
                            function (){
                                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                            });

                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    swal
                        ({
                            text: 'Falha ao alterar o cadastro do Usuário',
                            type: 'error',
                            timeout: 2500,
                            progressBar: true
                        });
                }
            });
    }
```

now I would like to update only the div with id="listlocation" so that only the existing divs in the database are displayed. I tried the way shown above but it didn't work.

[look divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AchK.png)

I tried to solve it with ajax but I don't have much experience with this method.

Comment: So you want to reload the list after deleting a record?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. I read the documentation but I couldn't replicate

Comment: You have to show your delete action

Comment: this deleting normally just need to update the div. I checked the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the easiest way to use javascript to create a user interface. You have to use a partial view in your case

```
@model ...your class

  @foreach (var item in Model.Points)
  {
      <div class=" border border-1 card list_divs p-3" id="@item.IdLocalizacao">

          <select required asp-for="@item.Location.Id" class="font-weight-bold teste-select input100" asp-items="ViewBag.Location">
          </select>

          <textarea asp-for="@item.title" id="DestinoObservacao" value="@item.title" class="border-0 input100"></textarea>
          <p class="text-primary" style="font-size: 15px;">@Model.Date1 - @Model.Date2</p>
          <button onclick="Delete(@item.Id)" class=" btn btn-outline-danger" value="@item.Id" type="button">Remove</button>
      </div>
  }
```

and main view should be

```
<div id="listlocation" class="tamanhopredefinido  overflow-auto col-5">
<partial name="_PartialPoints" />

 </div>
```

and action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> delete (string id)
{
    // ...  your code creating Model.Points
    return PartialView("_PartialPoints", viewModel);
}
```

and ajax

```
success: function (result) {
 $("#listlocation").html(result);
 },
```